# How to SELECT the following element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a group of nested divs

```
<div id="myDivs">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using jquery, how do I select the div that is immediately beneathe myDivs, but NONE of it's children?

thnx!

Comment: if that is the case , you can give some class name or id right?

Comment: A really great reference on all types of selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/): `$('#myDivs > div')`

Comment: Remember that this will select every `div` that is underneath myDivs directly. So if you only need the first one I think: `$('#myDivs > div:first-child')` would be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Since the first element is an id selector, the following way will faster. But only noticed the difference in a very complex document.

```
$('#myDivs').find('div')
```

Comment: This will also find all divs, not only the immediate children.

Comment: Sorry I didn't metion that requirement. `$('#myDivs').find('> div')` will find only immediate children.